# invalid syntax cause by += in ternany

Tags: python, python-3.x

it's working fine when using normal if else

```
vocab = {"a": "4", "i": "1", "u": "5", "e": "3", "o": "0"}

firstchar_name = input("Your name : ") # give fruit suggestion
fruitfrom_name = input("First Character of your name is {}, write any fruit that started with {} : ".format(firstchar_name[0], firstchar_name[0]))
favorite_number = input("Your favorite one-digit number : ")
date_of_born = input("Input your born date (date-month-year) : ")

to_alay = ""

word = list(fruitfrom_name.lower())
for char in word:
    to_alay += char if char not in vocab else to_alay += vocab[char]

print(to_alay)
```

Error :

```
$ python3 telemakita_password.py        
  File "telemakita_password.py", line 12                                                  
    to_alay += char if char not in vocab else to_alay += vocab[char]                      
                                                       ^                                  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i wondering why `+=` in if is working but not `+=` in else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because this is *not* an if-then-else statement. It is a [*ternary operator expression* (or *conditional expression*)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), this is an expression. This is the expression part:

```
char if char not in vocab else vocab[char]
```

`var += ...` is *not* an expression, it is *statement*. This is however not a problem, we can write:

```
to_alay += char if char not in vocab else vocab[char]
```

Python interprets this as:

```
to_alay += (char if char not in vocab else vocab[char])
```

so this basically does what you want.

## Using [`dict.get(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

That being said, I think by using `.get(..)`, you make life easier:

```
for char in word:
    to_alay += vocab.get(char, char)
```

This is more "self explaining", each iteration you aim to get the value that corresponds to `char` in the `vocab` dict, and if that key can not be found, you fallback to `char`.

We can even use `''.join(..)` here:

```
to_alay = ''.join(vocab.get(char, char) for char in word)
```

Comment: thankyou for explanation and `vocab.get(char, char)` syntax